# SQL Query Syntax Error: Trying to query last n number of rows in table

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I currently have the query:

```
SELECT
    sym,
    tstamp,
    COUNT(*) AS trades
FROM
    datas
GROUP BY
    tstamp,
    sym
HAVING COUNT(tstamp) > 500
```

I am trying to run the same query but instead of running it on the whole table (60 million rows added daily) I just want to run it on the last say 100,000 rows of data. This is what I have tried so far but getting syntax error:

```
SELECT
    sym,
    tstamp,
    COUNT(*) AS trades
FROM
    datas OFFSET 100000;
GROUP BY
    tstamp,
    sym
HAVING COUNT(tstamp) > 500
```

Comment: If you just want to use a (random) percentage of the rows, you could use `from the_table tablesample sample (20)`. Another option would be to partition this on the timestamp column so that you only need to hit the partition from "today"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as the "last X rows of data" in a table, because SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.

If you want to base the ordering on `tstamp`, then you can use a subquery:

```
SELECT sym, tstamp, COUNT(*) AS trades
FROM (SELECT d.*
      FROM datas d
      ORDER BY tstamp DESC
      LIMIT 100000
     ) d
GROUP BY tstamp, sym
HAVING COUNT(*) > 500;
```

If you are doing this for performance reasons, you will want an index on `datas(tstamp desc)`.

Comment: I am doing this for performance. It's currently taking me around 43 seconds to query through the entire table and I need query results to come in <5 seconds. Will having an index help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: @c0lton . . . An index will help a lot with performance.